# Finding the Probability of a Probability Using binomial

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-theorem

The exercise goes like this:

Let $X$ be $Bin(n,p)$ where $n=10$ and $p$ can be either $1/4$ or $3/4$, where both possibilities of $p$ are equally likely. It is known that $X=7$. What is the probability that $p=3/4$

If $P(X=7)= \binom{10}{7} p^7 (1-p)^3$ Do I have to solve some sort of inequality like: $\binom{10}{7} (1/4)^7 (3/4)^3 = \binom{10}{7} (3/4)^7 (1/4)^3 =1/2$ ?

Comment: Use Bayes' theorem.

Comment: As pointed by @Eckard you can use Bayes' theorem.Here is how:let E be the event X=7,A and B be the events p=/4 and p=3/4 ,respectively.We want P(B|E).We are given P(A)=P(B)=1/2 and since X is Bin(10,p) we can calculate P(E|A) and P(E|B) and hece apply Bayes'theorem to get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Bayes' theorem:
$$P(A|B)=P(B|A)\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$$
where $A$ is the event $p=\frac 34$, and $B$ is the event $X=7$. All of $P(A|B)$, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ can be calculated, so you can calculate $P(A|B)$ too.

Note that
$$P(B)=P(X=7)=P\left(X=7\left|p=\frac 14\right.\right)P\left(p=\frac 14\right)
+P\left(X=7\left|p=\frac 34\right.\right)P\left(p=\frac 34\right)
$$

Comment: So... $\binom{10}{7} (1/4)^7 (3/4)^3 + \binom{10}{7} (3/4)^7 (1/4)^3 = \frac{45}{65536}$ right?

Comment: What about the "equally likely" statement? I thought we should put some sort of "1/2" there

Comment: From the 'equally likely', you can conclude $P(p=\frac 14)=P(\frac 34)=\frac 12$. This is the input for the (updated) calculation.